# What is the intent of the pointer arithmetic in this code?

Tags: c

What does this line of code do, `newnode -> item.string = (char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);`, in the below example?

```
int nodesize = sizeof(log_t) + strlen(data.string) + 1;
newnode = (log_t *)malloc(nodesize);
if (newnode == NULL) return -1;

// What is this line doing:
newnode -> item.string = (char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);

strcpy(newnode -> item.string, data.string);
```

where `newnode` is the variable of type `log_t` (`log_t` has a variable named `item` of type `data_t`).  `data_t` has a property `char *string`.

Is this code setting up the buffer size of string?

Comment: C does not have a string type.

Comment: Olaf, as stated in my comments to one of the answers, that is entirely true. It's also entirely irrelevant :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
newnode -> item.string = (char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);
```

The right side will take the pointer `newnode`, cast it to a character pointer then add the size of an object to it.

This gives a pointer `n` bytes beyond `newnode`, where `n` is the size of the `log_t` object.

It then places this pointer value into the `string` member of the `item` member of the object pointed to by `newnode`.

Without seeing the actual structures in use, it's a little hard to tell *why* this is being done but my best guess would be that it's to provide an efficient self-referential pointer.

In other words, the pointer within `newnode` will point to an actual part of the `newnode` itself, or part of a larger memory block that was allocated which contains a `newnode` object at the start of it. And, since you state that `newnode` is of the type `log_t`, it must be the latter case (a type cannot contain a copy of itself - it can contain a *pointer* to the type itself but not a *actual* copy).

---

An example of where this may come in handy is an object allocation where small sizes are satisfied completely by the object itself but larger ones are handled differently, such as with an `int`-to-`string` map entry:

```
typedef struct {
    int  id;
    char *string;
} hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    hdr_t hdr;
    char  smallBuff[31];
} entry_t;
```

In the case where you want to populate an `entry_t` variable with a 500-character string, you would allocate the string separately then just set up `string` to point to it.

However, for a string of thirty characters or less, you could just create it in `smallBuff` then set `string` to point to that instead (no separate memory needed). That would be done with:

```
entry_t *entry = malloc (sizeof (*entry)); // should check for NULL.
entry->hdr.id = 7;
entry->hdr.string = (char*)entry + sizeof (hdr_t);
strcpy (entry->hdr.string, "small string");
```

The third line in that sample above is *very* similar to what you have in your code.

---

Similarly (and probably more apropos to your case), you can allocate more memory than you need and use it:

```
typedef struct {
    int  id;
    char *string;
} entry_t;

char *str = "small string";
entry_t *entry = malloc (sizeof (*entry) + strlen (str) + 1); // with extra bytes.
entry->id = 7;
entry->string = (char*)entry + sizeof (entry_t);
strcpy (entry->string, str);
```

Comment: Not really a part of the `newnode`, most likely the memory that follows `log_t` structure in a block allocated to a larger size precisely for this purpose.  This can be done more cleanly in C99 with a flexible array.

Comment: @chqrlie, could go either way there. It may be in the `newnode` struct itself or it may be beyond the end of the actual `newnode` but in a larger memory block. I've updated to include the latter as well.

Comment: the OP wrote: *`newnode` is the variable of type `log_t`* we should assume he meant a pointer to `log_t`, therefore `(char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);` cannot fall inside the `newnode`.

Comment: @chqrlie, yes, missed that, updated sample code to take into account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the memory for newnode was allocated with additional space for the string.

The result is the same, but I'd personally write that as `newnode->item.string = (char*) &newnode[1];`

That is, the storage space for string is immediately after the log_t object.  This is sometimes done when a single chunk of memory has been allocated in advance, and objects and their members all point to memory in this chunk.  It's been done in the past to cut down on the overhead of small memory allocations.

If log_t is 32 bytes, and the string is 16 bytes long (including the nul terminator!), you could malloc 48 bytes, point the string member to the 32nd byte of this memory allocation and copy the string there.

Comment: Why not `newnode->item.string = (char*)(newnode + 1);`?

Comment: Yes you're right newnode is allocated before that line.  Which confused me because I thought it already set up enough memory space during the allocation.

Comment: @Jasep88: post the allocation code, I'm willing to bet it allocates **more** memory than needed for the `log_t` structure.

Comment: @chqrlie Personal preference, and I've probably seen or made a `(char*) newnode + 1` mistake at least once in life.

Comment: C does not have a string type.

Comment: `int nodesize;
nodesize = sizeof(log_t)+strlen(data.string) +1;
if ((newnode = (log_t *)(malloc(nodesize))) == NULL);
  return -1;`

data is the parameter of type data_t in this function

Comment: @Olaf, that's rather pedantic. Yes, there's no builtin *type* called string but C has strings, has had them for a *very* long time. The fact that they're character arrays with a NUL terminator doesn't make them any less real. You may want to actually *count* how often the word string appears in the standard :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Feel free to provide a link to the C standard of that string **type**! It is an very important issue with C that "strings" are just a convention for library functions with the only compiler-support of _string literals_ which are actually `const char []`. One result from this lack of a string type is you cannot compare two "strings" with comparsion operators. And note that a C "string" actually is an array of integers, becaus C also does not have a true character type either. `char` is an integer type. Maybe you read about languages like Python, Modula or Pascal.

Comment: @paxdiablo: One effect from this lack of a string type is `sizeof(str)` does not yield the length of the string.

Comment: @Olaf, you should re-read my comment. I know that there's no string type. I'm just stating that your comment was pedantic because (1) C *has* strings despite them not being a core type and (2) there's no mention of a string type in the question, this answer or any of the comments to this answer (until you bought it up). If you were going to complain about the deficiencies of C (and I freely admit they exist), this is probably the wrong place to do it.

Comment: You may also want to look up "non sequiter" :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's doing pointer arithmetic.  In C, when you add a value to a pointer, it moves the pointer by that value * the size of the type pointed to by the pointer.

What this is doing is casting newnode to a char*, so that the pointer arithmetic is done assuming that newnode is a char*, thus the size of the data it points to is 1.  It them adds the sizeof(log_t) which is the size of type log_t.  Based on your description of log_t, it looks like it contains a single char*, so its size would be the size of a pointer, either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the architecture.

So, this will set `newnode.item.string` to be `sizeof(log_t)` bytes after address that newnode contains.